# Edit file with vim using Dialog

Tags: shell-script, process-management, dialog

I am trying to build a terminal based GUI for a tool. The following code invokes something like this

```
while true
do
   CHOICE=$(dialog --keep-window --clear --no-shadow \
                --backtitle "$BACKTITLE" \
                --title "$TITLE" \
                --menu "$MENU" \
                $HEIGHT $WIDTH $CHOICE_HEIGHT \
                "${OPTIONS[@]}" \
                2>&1 >/dev/tty)

   clear

   case $CHOICE in
   #*) exec vim "$(echo $CHOICE  | cut -d ':' -f 1)" ;  ;;
   *)  filename="$(echo $CHOICE | cut -d ':' -f 1)"
       #mkfifo "$TOMATO_DIR/cf"
       if [ ! -z $filename ] ; then
           dialog --editbox $filename 60 80
           #cp "$TOMATO_DIR/cf" $filename
           #rm -f ${INPUT}
       else
           clear
           exit 0
       fi
       clear ;;
   esac

done
```

[image]

And on pressing `ENTER` and editbox as following opens:
[image]

I tried opening the file in `vim` but on saving the file, the tools exits.
**I want to know, how to open the file and return to the tool on saving or exiting from `vim` ?**

Comment: did you use `exec vim ... ` or `vim ...` in former case, shell will be replaced by vim, and upon vim exit will dissapear. try using later case.

Comment: @Archemar That worked perfectly !! Can you please explain why this happens ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exec is a shell builtin as per `bash` man page (be patient, it is far away)

```
   exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]
          If command is specified, it replaces the shell.  No new process is created.
```

consider 2 script

```
exec ls
pwd
```

and

```
ls
pwd
```

if you execute the first shell, `exec ls` command will replace shell (discarding remaining input), `pwd` command will never get exectued.